# When I try to submit a form, Not the values changed by me but the initial values are transferred to action page

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, user-defined-functions

```
<script>
function mySubmit(index) {
    if(index==3){
        document.myForm.action='update.jsp';
    }   
    if(index==4){
        document.myForm.action='';  
    }   
    document.myForm.submit();
}</script>
```

This is my javascript function. And I use this from the code below.

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name=num id=num value=<%=article.getNum() %>>
                    ...

                    <td class="col-md-2">작성자</td>
                    <td class="col-md-8"><input disabled="disabled" type=text name="writer" id="writer" value="<%=article.getWriter()%> "></td>

                </tr>

                   ...
                <tr>
                    <td>비밀번호</td>
                    <td><input type=password name="passwd" id="passwd"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td id="buttons" colspan="2">
                    <input class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" value="글수정" onclick="mySubmit(3)">
                    <input class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" value="글삭제" onclick="mySubmit(4)">
                    <input class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="button" value="목록보기" onclick="location.href='list.jsp'">
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
```

This is a revising article page. I want to transfer values changed from original values, but it didn't work. It only transfer original values which are initialized in my code.

HELP!!

Comment: Where are you getting the value from? Because in your code you are sending the default value as mySubmit(3)...

Comment: Missing some quotation marks on your hidden input and second table data elements.

Comment: @JegadeshBS I am getting the values from Browser ~! :(

Comment: @ZachA OHH!! Nevermind~! It also work without quotation marks!

Comment: Can you please give the full HTML code